# Message box that cannot save in table

Tags: sql, visual-foxpro

```
IF EMPTY(thisform.docnum.value)=.T. or EMPTY(thisform.doctype.value)=.T. then
    MESSAGEBOX("Unabled to save all fields required !",0+64,"Warning")
ELSE    
    IF EMPTY(thisform.doctitle.value)=.T. or EMPTY(thisform.docdate.value)=.T. then
    MESSAGEBOX("Unabled to save all fields required !",0+64,"Warning")  
ELSE 
    IF EMPTY(thisform.recdate.value)=.T. or EMPTY(thisform.pubdate.value)=.T. then
    MESSAGEBOX("Unabled to save all fields required !",0+64,"Warning")  
ELSE 
    IF EMPTY(thisform.sector.value)=.T. or EMPTY(thisform.cluster.value)=.T. then
    MESSAGEBOX("Unabled to save all fields required !",0+64,"Warning")   
ELSE 
    IF EMPTY(thisform.region.value)=.T. or EMPTY(thisform.revision.value)=.T. then
    MESSAGEBOX("Unabled to save all fields required !",0+64,"Warning")   
ELSE 
    IF EMPTY(thisform.procby.value)=.T. or EMPTY(thisform.revby.value)=.T. then
    MESSAGEBOX("Unabled to save all fields required !",0+64,"Warning")   
ELSE 
    IF EMPTY(thisform.encby.value)=.T.  then 
ELSE    
    MESSAGEBOX("Unabled to save all fields required !",0+64,"Warning")
```

My add button it work when i click and no one input in my text box the warning message will pop-up but it can save it in my table. can you help me what i problem with my codes that when no one will input it cannot save in my table. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your code is very hard to read and incomplete and looks like your last expression is incorrect. Probably you meant this:

```
If Empty(Thisform.docnum.Value) Or Empty(Thisform.doctype.Value) Or ;
        Empty(Thisform.doctitle.Value) Or Empty(Thisform.docdate.Value) Or ;
        Empty(Thisform.recdate.Value) Or Empty(Thisform.pubdate.Value) Or ;
        Empty(Thisform.sector.Value) Or Empty(Thisform.cluster.Value) Or ;
        Empty(Thisform.Region.Value) Or Empty(Thisform.revision.Value) Or ;
        Empty(Thisform.procby.Value) Or Empty(Thisform.revby.Value) Or ;
        Empty(Thisform.encby.Value)
    Messagebox("Unabled to save all fields required !",0+64,"Warning")
Else
  * Save operation
Endif
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at your final `IF`statement. You have the `MessageBox` telling the "Unable to save" when all of the fields actually have a value.

Maybe try changing it to this:

```
IF EMPTY(THISFORM.docnum.VALUE)=.T. OR EMPTY(THISFORM.doctype.VALUE)=.T. then
    MESSAGEBOX("Unabled to save all fields required !",0+64,"Warning")
ELSE
    IF EMPTY(THISFORM.doctitle.VALUE)=.T. OR EMPTY(THISFORM.docdate.VALUE)=.T. then
        MESSAGEBOX("Unabled to save all fields required !",0+64,"Warning")
    ELSE
        IF EMPTY(THISFORM.recdate.VALUE)=.T. OR EMPTY(THISFORM.pubdate.VALUE)=.T. then
            MESSAGEBOX("Unabled to save all fields required !",0+64,"Warning")
        ELSE
            IF EMPTY(THISFORM.sector.VALUE)=.T. OR EMPTY(THISFORM.cluster.VALUE)=.T. then
                MESSAGEBOX("Unabled to save all fields required !",0+64,"Warning")
            ELSE
                IF EMPTY(THISFORM.REGION.VALUE)=.T. OR EMPTY(THISFORM.revision.VALUE)=.T. then
                    MESSAGEBOX("Unabled to save all fields required !",0+64,"Warning")
                ELSE
                    IF EMPTY(THISFORM.procby.VALUE)=.T. OR EMPTY(THISFORM.revby.VALUE)=.T. then
                        MESSAGEBOX("Unabled to save all fields required !",0+64,"Warning")
                    ELSE
                        IF EMPTY(THISFORM.encby.VALUE)=.T.  then
                            MESSAGEBOX("Unabled to save all fields required !",0+64,"Warning")
                        ELSE
                            **All fields have values here, save to table**
                        ENDIF
                    ENDIF
                ENDIF
            ENDIF
        ENDIF
    ENDIF
ENDIF
```

You could try using a `CASE` statement for this as well to make it more organized and easier to read.

```
DO CASE
    CASE EMPTY(THISFORM.docnum.VALUE) OR  EMPTY(THISFORM.doctype.VALUE)
        MESSAGEBOX("Unabled to save all fields required !",0+64,"Warning")

    CASE EMPTY(THISFORM.doctitle.VALUE) OR EMPTY(THISFORM.docdate.VALUE)
        MESSAGEBOX("Unabled to save all fields required !",0+64,"Warning")

    OTHERWISE
        **code to save to table**
ENDCASE
```